# Find if 2 vectors have 4 consecutive identical elements

Tags: matlab, vector

I am trying to compare 2 vectors to discover if they share 4 consecutive values.

For example

```
w = [6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]
v = [5 6 7 8 9]
```

Has 4 consecutive values `6 7 8 9`

But

```
x = [6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]
y = [6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 13 14]
```

has four identical values (`6 7 13 14`) but they aren't consecutive.

The code I am currently using is:

```
if length(intersect(v, w)) >= 4
    condition = true;
```

but this doesn't test for consecutive elements, so it would return `true` for both cases listed above whereas I want it to only return `true` for the first case.

Can somebody please help me find a way to test for identical consecutive elements rather than just identical elements.

Comment: Do the positions inside the array or the numbers themselves have to be consecutive?

Comment: Your examples aren't clear. `6 7 8 9` are consecutive numbers and also consecutively placed. `6 7 13 14` are not consectutive number nor are they consecutively placed in your second `y`. So which is the problem, that the numbers aren't consecutive or that they aren't place consecutively?

Comment: @Dan They have to be consecutive numbers as they relate to times. The vectors are calculated from times at which certain weather conditions are met. I am trying to find if both weather conditions are met for at least 4 hours. In this case, because it only goes from 1- 24 in order, consecutive numbers will be placed consecutively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Marcos' answer:

1. Create all possible search vectors from your initial search (i.e. `[5 6 7 8] [6 7 8 9]`) - however we will make it a 3D matrix which will be *`m`*-by-*1*-by-*`n`*

   ```
   n = 4;
   m = numel(v)-n+1;
   V = permute(v(bsxfun(@plus,(0:m-1)',1:n)),[1,3,2])
   ```
2. Check if any of these sub-vectors are a subset of the vector being searched

   ```
   check = sum(any(bsxfun(@eq, V, w),3),2) >= n;
   match = squeeze(V(check,:,:))'  %'// The ' is debatable here, it depends on how many matches you get
   ```

Comment: This looks nice but doesn't it lead to major memory requirements for long-ish input vectors?  I'd like to see a way to compare w/o holding all possible permutations in memory simultaneously.   I'm thinking maybe do a convolution and identify the peak?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft [Shai's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33755847/1011724) uses convolution. But if memory is an issue, then just replace the `bsxfun`s with `for`-loops...

Answer (score 1):

you can compare

```
bsxfun(@eq, w,v')
```

Resulting with

```
ans =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

As you can see four consecutive matching elements form a diagonal of length 4.
To find the location of this diagonal you can `conv2` with a 4 diagonal filter (`eye(4)`):

```
[rr cc] = find( conv2( single(bsxfun(@eq, [1 2 3 w],v')), eye(4), 'same' ) == 4 )
```

compensating for the center of the filter

```
loc_in_w = cc - 1
loc_in_v = rr - 1
```

yielding

```
 loc_in_w =
 1

 loc_in_v = 
 2
```

which are the first index of the sequence in `w`  and `v` respectively.

This method can work with more than one occurrence of a 4-substring of `v` in `w`...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't meddled in matlab for ages, but my "general" approach to this in computing terms would be splitting the problem into a needle-and-haystack solution with two parts:

1. Create all possible search vectors from your initial search (i.e. [5 6 7 8] [6 7 8 9])
2. Check if any of these sub-vectors are a subset of the vector being searched.

Basically just two set-operations in a row.

Comment: I fear this answer is like the Monty Python "How to play the flute: you blow here and wiggle your fingers there."  :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your vectors to strings, and use `strfind`.
If `x` and `y` are your vectors:

```
x_str = mat2str(x);    
y_str = mat2str(y);
n = strfind(x_str(2:end-1), y_str(2:end-1))
```

Note that you have to remove the first and last characters of the string version, as they correspond to the square brackets of the vectors.

Comment: This fails because the OP wants to find matching substrings, not all of `x_str` in `y_str`

Comment: AFAIK, `strfind` finds matching substrings [link](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html). Having said that, it doesn't answer the OP's question because the numbers themselves have to consecutive -- which was latter clarified.